# undefined local variable or method `availability_params' for #<AvailabilitiesController>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I'm trying to create new availability object in a program and all of the sudden I can't find availabilities_params. Not sure what is going on exactly.

```
class AvailabilitiesController < ApplicationController

def create
    @availability = Availability.new(availability_params)
    @availability.save

    if member_signed_in?
      redirect_to member_path(current_member)
    elsif provider_signed_in?
      redirect_to provider_path(current_provider)
    end

end

def new
    @availability = Availability.new
end

def show
    @availability
end

private

def availabilty_params
    params.require(:availability).permit(:time, :date, :provider_id, :user_id)
end


end
```

Here is the form to create availability

```
= form_for(@availability) do |f|
   =    f.date_field :date, :min=> "2014-11-00", :value => "2015-01-01"
   = f.time_field :time, :placeholder => "Available Time"
   -if member_signed_in?
     = f.hidden_field :member_id, value: current_member.id
   -elsif provider_signed_in?
     = f.hidden_field :provider_id, value: current_provider.id
= f.submit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a typo in the method name. It should be `def availability_params` rather than `def availabilty_params`.

Comment: oh god i just saw that too

Comment: It's probably a hint that you might need a coffee break ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your create action, you had this

```
 @availability = Availability.new(availability_params)
```

In your `availability_params` method you had this

```
def availabilty_params
    params.require(:availability).permit(:time, :date, :provider_id, :user_id)
end
```

Please change`availabilty_params` to `availability_params`